# What is the difference between 'You want something' and 'You want something done'?

Tags: object-past-participle

I exactly don't know the meaning of 'Something done'

Is it kind of passive?

If someone said "that means 'you want something done", What is that means?

Comment: "I want those windows cleaned. And I want it done by 5 p.m."   Clear?    I advise you to visit our sister site, ELL, where you will certainly receive more explanations about it.

Comment: Object past participle, 112 questionshttp://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=object+past+participle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "**want something done**" simply means you are looking for someone to take action.

For example:

```
Boss: "The shipment is late, where is it?"
Worker: "I'm not sure, do you want something done about it?"
Boss: "Of course!"
```

In the previous scenario the boss is complaining about something. The worker then asks if the boss wants the worker to take an action to fix the problem.

As for the difference between just **wanting something** and **wanting something done** you can think of **wanting something** as referring to the desire to receive something as opposed to the desire to have someone take action.

Comment: I totally understood what you are talking about. REALLY  THANK YOU very much! Now I can find the difference between them.